# Possible to have AngularJs and Angular (v7) in the same application?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

We have a AngularJs site and we are planning to upgrade to Angular.

I understand that there is ngUpgrade but I am thinking to have Angular in the same application but only use it for the new pages so that the existing/current pages work the same until we updated them.

Is this possible to have two Angular (AngularJs and Angular) and how can it be done?

Comment: Maybe it's possible but I strongly suggest to make a complete upgrade to Angular. Even if Angular is the upgrade of AngularJS, the two frameworks works almost completely differently and they have very few points in common

Comment: @MatteoMeil I do agree. The site was done by previous developers and I do not have AngularJS experience. That's why I do not want to use ngUpgrade. I wouldn't know if the existing functions stop working and I still do not know the complete system.
So I am thinking to have both Angular but only use it for the new pages but not sure if it can be achievable. All the google results show ngUpgrade or complete rewrite. :(

Comment: This is not a duplicate question and there's no answer for me there. I want to have both Angular and AngularJs in the application but only run one based on the page served. Read it carefully @georgeawg